# I don't understand part of the objective-c documentation on setting a value

Tags: objective-c

Here is what the documentayion says. Here are declarations in the interface file.

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;

@property NSString *lastName;

@end
```

Next it says:
Use Accessor Methods to Get or Set Property Values

You access or set an object’s properties via accessor methods:

```
NSString *firstName = [somePerson firstName];

[somePerson setFirstName:@"Johnny"];
```

I don't understand what "somePerson" is referring to. Where did it come from?

Comment: somePerson is an instance of this interface, its coming from some other code not provided here, probably this code should be written by you

Answer (score 5):

In this sample, `somePerson` is probably an instance of the `XYZPerson` class.  The code author just assumed that you would realize this.

```
// create a person
XYZPerson *somePerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];

// set that person's "firstName" property to "Johnny"
[somePerson setFirstName: @"Johnny"]

// Get the firstName property of the somePerson object
NSString *personsName = [somePerson firstName];

// personsName should be the string "Johnny"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a second look at the docs.  It did kind of pop out of nowhere, but it gives you a sense of how to use it in the future.  I'd recommend looking at this part in the link below, which should be the docs you are referring to:

**Getting** a value using *somePerson.firstName* is the same as using [somePerson firstName]

**Setting** a value using *somePerson.firstName* = @"Johnny" is the same as using [somePerson setFirstName:@"Johnny"]

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 0):

From the previous chapter "Objects Send and Receive Messages":

> Assuming you’ve got hold of an XYZPerson object, you could send it the sayHello message like this:
>
> `[somePerson sayHello];`

The code author just assumed that you had seen somePerson before.